# Pymongo BulkWriteResult doesn't contain upserted_ids

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert, upsert

Okey so currently I'm trying to upsert something in a local mongodb using pymongo.(I check to see if the document is in the db and if it is, update it, otherwise just insert it)

I'm using bulk_write to do that, and everything is working ok. The data is inserted/updated.

However, i would need the ids of the newly inserted/updated documents but the "upserted_ids" in the bulkWriteResult object is empty, even if it states that it inserted 14 documents.

I've added this screenshot with the variable. Is it a bug? or is there something i'm not aware of?

[image: debug_screenshot]

Finally, is there a way of getting the ids of the documents without actually searching for them in the db? (If possible, I would prefer to use bulk_write)

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
As suggested, i added a part of the code so it's easier to get the general ideea:

```
for name in input_list:
    if name not in stored_names: #completely new entry (both name and package)
        operations.append(InsertOne({"name": name, "package" : [package_name]}))

if len(operations) == 0:
    print ("## No new permissions to insert")
    return
bulkWriteResult = _db_insert_bulk(collection_name,operations)
```

and the insert function:

```
def _db_insert_bulk(collection_name,operations_list):
    return db[collection_name].bulk_write(operations_list)
```

Comment: maybe include the command you're running

Comment: There's no way to get any detail of updated docs from write operation. You can only get stats. You can write custom function to achieve this by leveraging `findOneAndUpdate` with `{new: true, upsert: true}`. using `new: true` will return you the update document and inserted document.

Comment: If you are asking about pymongo behavior, reference pymongo documentation where this behavior is described.

Answer (score 2):

The `upserted_ids` field in the pymongo `BulkWriteResult` only contains the ids of the records that have been inserted **as part of an upsert operation**, e.g. an `UpdateOne` or `ReplaceOne` with the `upsert=True` parameter set.

As you are performing `InsertOne` which doesn't have an `upsert` option, the `upserted_ids` list will be empty.

The lack of an `inserted_ids` field in pymongo's BulkWriteResult in an omission in the drivers; technically it conforms to crud specificaiton mentioned in D. SM's answer as it is annotated as "Drivers may choose to not provide this property.".

But ... there is an answer. If you are **only** doing inserts as part of your bulk update (and not mixed bulk operations), just use `insert_many()`. It is just as efficient as a bulk write and, crucially, does provide the `inserted_ids` value in the `InsertManyResult` object.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

inserts = [{'foo': 'bar'}]

result = db.test.insert_many(inserts, ordered=False)
print(result.inserted_ids)
```

Prints:

```
[ObjectId('5fb92cafbe8be8a43bd1bde0')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is part of [crud specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/crud/crud.rst) and should be implemented by compliant drivers including pymongo. Reference pymongo documentation for correct usage.

Example in Ruby:

```
irb(main):003:0> c.bulk_write([insert_one:{a:1}])
=> #<Mongo::BulkWrite::Result:0x00005579c42d7dd0 @results={"n_inserted"=>1, "n"=>1, "inserted_ids"=>[BSON::ObjectId('5fb7e4b12c97a60f255eb590')]}>
```

Your output shows that zero documents were upserted, therefore there wouldn't be any ids associated with the upserted documents.

Your code doesn't appear to show any upserts at all, which again means you won't see any upserted ids.

Comment: very well then, but there are no operations named "UpsertOne", only InsertOne,UpdateOne,ReplaceOne and DeleteOne. If that field will not be modified, why would it be there in the first place? Furthermore, there is no attribute named "inserted_ids"

Comment: Upsert is a modifier on update operations (update/replace). It is not an operation. Fields are uniform because you always get a bulk write result. Again, see the driver documentation for correct usage.